# How to combine the blue theme and the dark theme for the code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes

How would you do to combine the dark theme for the code editor with the blue theme for the rest of the Visual Studio UI, is there a way to pick independent configurations for each one?

`Blue default theme with dark editor`

Using Visual Studio 2012, update 2 introduced the old Blue theme from VS2010 also available in VS2013 Preview

Comment: I guess you can do it with [Color Theme Editor extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05)

Comment: Would be nice if you can give some feedback to the leaved comments and answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think the combination I'm trying to do is not yet possible `Color Theme Editor extension` doesn't allow you to do it and when you export the configuration of the fonts in the editor it exports the GUIDs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) to do this. Take one of the two themes as base for your edits and change it in the way you need to get a new theme. I do it for my self with other themes - no problems at all.

Comment: Hi @micha it only allows to modify UI elements and it does it one by one. What I'd to do is pick a different code editor theme for a particular UI theme.

Comment: Yes, you have to it one by one. Take Blue-Theme and edit the code-editor parts as you need. In my eyes and as you mentioned there is no such difference between "UI theme" and "code editor theme".

Comment: Could you upload your result?

Comment: @Joe: Unfortunately no. I no longer have the theme. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the [Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) is the right answer. And you don't need to edit the color one by one. You can create a copy of the black theme, type "text editor" in the upper right search field, and then select all the filtered items in the main window, copy them, and paste to a copy of the blue theme with "text editor" filter in place. I did this in 1 minute!

This [Channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-2012-Color-Theme-Editor) explains how to do this, you can just watch the first 7 minutes.